# Keep a MemoryMappedFile Alive after Dispose

Tags: c#, winapi, shared-memory

I need to access a shared memory map file (created and owned by a separate program); To do so I'm using

```
_map = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(
            "buffer",
            MemoryMappedFileRights.ReadWrite, 
            HandleInheritability.None);

_mapAccessor = _map.CreateViewAccessor(0, 0, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

When I close the application I call dispose on these:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    if (_mapAccessor != null)
        _mapAccessor.Dispose();

    if (_map != null)
        _map.Dispose();
}
```

but it seems like something I'm doing here is killing off the memory map file, because the other program that uses this starts getting protected memory faults.

*If I dispose the `_map` does it actually destroy the memory mapped file, even though its not inherited ownership?*

**Update**

Turns out the other program, not under my control, was doing naughty things after I had signaled it to go-to idle mode (immediately before disposing the memory map).

When using 'MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting' with 'HandleInheritability.None' the memory map file will not be destroyed after dispose.

Comment: No, disposing a MemoryMappedFile opened by calling `OpenExisting()` will *not* destroy the underlying MMF. The process that called the Windows API `CreateFileMapping()` controls the lifetime of the MMF and `OpenExisting()` calls `OpenFileMapping()` instead.

Comment: You'd better focus on the content of the mmf and the synchronization objects you need that make accessing the mmf safe.  That you don't seem to have any such synchronization in place is a pretty big Red Flag btw.

Comment: You are right Hans, it wasn't the memory map that was the problem, it was simply the other program (not mine) doing naughty things with a driver, after I had signaled a go-to idle mode.

Comment: @MatthewWatson can you paste your comment as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @MeirionHughes OK, done. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, disposing a MemoryMappedFile opened by calling OpenExisting() will not destroy the underlying MMF.

The process that called the Windows API CreateFileMapping() controls the lifetime of the MMF and OpenExisting() calls OpenFileMapping() instead.